# Using information from the first API in the second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a small question. I need to fetch two API: I need to call the first one, and then use the information from the first one in the second one. Could you please help me with the solution?

Here is my current code, but I cannot grab somehow the result of the first fetch (which I can see in the console and stuff, so it's not a problem; I just need to grab data from there).

```
    function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});


  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result);
        })
        .then((result) => {
          const data = fetch(`${api.base}onecall?lat=${result.city.coord.lat}&lon=${result.city.coord.lon}&APPID=${api.key}`)
          console.log(data)
        })
        
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the result in `then` of `promise` since it creates a new promise out of returned value.

```
const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result);
          return result; // add return statement 
        })
        .then((result) => {
          const data = fetch(`${api.base}onecall?lat=${result.city.coord.lat}&lon=${result.city.coord.lon}&APPID=${api.key}`)
          data.then((res)=>res.json())
              .then(result=>{
                  console.log(result)
               })
        })
        
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hm, yeah - I thought it was that and tried to add a return statement before, but still get the "promise pending" log in the console.

Comment: @MrVoland in console.log of 2nd api ? It will show pending since it's again a promise, you need to use `then` to get the results. I have updated my code for the same. Although, you can write more readable code with `asyn` `await`

Comment: riiiiiiight, I think I'm too tired for today - got it, works perfectly. Thanks for help mate :D